# X-Ray like Shading Error in EEVEE but not Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, shaders, eevee-render-engine, sculpting

I sculpted this Manta Ray and tried texturing it. I Noticed that when in EEVEE, somehow the base Geometry is clipping trough, as if i had the XRAY switched on. When i use EEVEE, this problem does not appear. Does anyone have an idea what might have gone wrong?

[image: The left hand picture shows the scene using cycles and not having issues, the righ thand one uses eevee and the issue is clearly visible.]

Comment: Is the alpha of the principled 1.0, or less than that?

Answer (score 2):

Ten to one, you have the shader blend method set to “Alpha blend,” which is useless for things more than one face thick. Use “alpha hashed” instead.

This is probably in the top 10 FAQ.